# Layers to be used after using a pretrained model: When to add GlobalAveragePooling2D()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

I am using pretrained models to classify image. My question is what kind of layers do I have to add after using the pretrained model structure in my model, resp. why these two implementations differ. To be specific:

Consider two examples, one using the cats and dogs dataset:

One implementation can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). The crucial point is that the base model:

```
# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
```

is frozen and a GlobalAveragePooling2D() is added, before a final tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) is added. So the model structure looks like:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  global_average_layer,
  prediction_layer
])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

So they added not only a final dense(1) layer, but also a GlobalAveragePooling2D() layer before.

The other using the tf flowers dataset:

In this [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub) it is different. A GlobalAveragePooling2D() is not added.

```
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/2" 

feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                         input_shape=(224,224,3))
feature_extractor_layer.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.Dense(image_data.num_classes)
])
```

Where image_data.num_classes is 5 representing the different flower classification. So in this example a GlobalAveragePooling2D() layer is not added.

I do not understand this. Why is this different? When to add a GlobalAveragePooling2D() or not? And what is better / should I do?

I am not sure if the reason is that in one case the dataset cats and dogs is binary classification and in the other it is a multiclass classifcation problem. Or the difference is that in one case `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` was used to load MobileNetV2 and in the other implementation `hub.KerasLayer` was used to get the feature_extractor. When I check the model in the first implementation:

[image: ex1]

I can see that the last layer is a relu activation layer.

When I check the feature_extractor:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.summary()
```

I get the output:

[image: ex2]

So maybe reason is also that I do not understand the difference between `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` vs `hub.KerasLayer`. The hub.KerasLayer just gives me the feature extractor. I know this, but still I think I did not get the difference between these two methods.

I cannot check the layers of the feature_extractor itself. So feature_extractor.summary() or feature_extractor.layers does not work. How can I inspect the layers here? And how can I know I should add GlobalAveragePooling2D or not?

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

> Why is this different? When to add a GlobalAveragePooling2D() or not? And what is better / should I do?

The first case it outputs 4 dimensional tensors that are raw outputs of the last convolutional layer. So, you need to flatten them somehow, and in this example you are using GlobalAveragePooling2D (but you could use any other strategy). I can't tell which is better: it depends on your problem, and depending on how `hub.KerasLayer` version implemented  the flatten, they could be exactly the same. That said, I'd just pickup one of them and go on: I don't see huge differences among them,

#### Long answer: understanding Keras implementation

The difference is in the output of both base models: in your keras examples, outputs are of shape `(bz, hh, ww, nf)` where `bz` is batch size, `hh` and `ww` are height and weight of the last convolutional layer in the model and `nf` is the number of filters (or convolutions) applied in this last layer.

So: this outputs the output of the last convolutions (or filters) of the base model.

Hence, you need to convert those outputs (which you can think them as images) to vectors of shape `(bz, n_feats)`, where `n_feats` is the number of features the base model is computing. Once this conversion is done, you can stack your classification layer (or as many layers as you want) because at this point you have vectors.

How to compute this conversion? Some common alternatives are taking the average or maximum among the convolutional output (which reduces the size), or you could just reshape them as a single row, or add more convolutional layers until you get a vector as an output (I strongly suggest to follow usual practices like average or maximum).

In your first example, when calling `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2`, you are using the default police with respect to this last year, and hence, the last convolutional layer is let "as is": some convolutions. You can modify this behavior with the param pooling, as documented [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/):

> **pooling**: Optional pooling mode for feature extraction when include_top is False.
>
> - `None` (default) means that the output of the model will be the 4D tensor output of the last convolutional block.
> - `avg` means that global average pooling will be applied to the output of the last convolutional block, and thus the output of the model will be a 2D tensor.
> - `max` means that global max pooling will be applied.

In summary, in your first example, you are building the base model without telling explicitly  what to do with the last layer, the model keeps returning 4 dimensional tensors that you immediately convert to vectors with the usage of average pooling, so you can avoid this explicit average pooling if you tell Keras to do it:

```py
# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               pooling='avg', # Tell keras to average last layer
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  # global_average_layer, -> not needed any more
  prediction_layer
])
```

#### TFHub implementation

Finally, when you use the TensorFlow Hub implementation, as you picked up the `feature_vector` version of the model, it already implements some kind of pooling (which I didn't found yet how) to make sure the model outputs vectors rather than 4 dimensional tensors. So, you don't need to add explicitly the layer to convert them because it is already done.

In my opinion, I prefer Keras implementation since it gives you more freedom to pick the strategy you want (in fact you could keep stacking whatever you want).

Answer (score -1):

Lets say there is a model taking [1, 208, 208, 3] images and has 6 pooling layers with kernels [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7] which would result in a feature column for image [1, 1, 1, 2048] for 2048 filters in the last conv layer. Note, how the last pooling layer accepts [1, 7, 7, 2048] inputs

If we relax the constrains for the input image (which is typically the case for object deteciton models) than after same set of pooling layers image of size [1, 104, 208, 3] would produce pre-last-pooling output of [1, 4, 7, 2024] and [1, 256, 408, 3] would yeild [1, 8, 13, 2048]. This maps would have about the same amount information as original  [1, 7, 7, 2048] but the original pooling layer would not produce a feature column wiht [1, 1, 1, N]. That is why we switch to global pooling layer.

In short, global pooling layer is important if we don't have strict restriction on the input image size (and don't resize the image as the first op in the model).

Comment: No, this is not correct. In both cases image size is resized. tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
 and in the other example target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE.

Answer (score -1):

I think difference in output of models
"https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/2" has output is 1d vector * batch_size, you  just can't apply Conv2D to it.

Output of tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2 probably more complex, thus you have more capability to transform one.